# How do .mp3 sizes compare to .wav sizes?

Tags: javascript, audio, mp3, wav

I've been working on converting `.mp3` files uploaded by a user into `.wav` format to be handled by the back-end.  I've been following [this example](https://gist.github.com/revolunet/46d4187c3b6f28632a91421c1f2a9fad), and I think it works, but the resultant `.wav` is bigger than the back-end wants to handle.  I don't know enough about the inner workings of audio makeup to understand what I can change to compress the final `.wav` file more, or if that's even possible.

Is it a straight 1:1 conversion, where a certain size `.mp3` will always become a certain size `.wav`?  That would be the easy answer, but there's so much config that seems to go into creating the `.wav`, I'm sure it's not that simple.

There's also practically no beginner-friendly documentation I can find that details what's actually going on in the conversion, like what these lines (and all the rest) are actually doing:

```
intBuffer[0] = 0x4952; // "RI"
intBuffer[1] = 0x4646; // "FF"
```

Any help here would be immensely appreciated, I think I'm over my head here.

Comment: _"There's also practically no documentation I can find that details what's actually going on"_ -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mp3#Encoding_and_decoding

Comment: @Andreas That's great, thank you, but do you know of any resource that I can understand with no background in audio language? That's practically Greek to me at this stage.

Comment: there may well be a 1:1 mapping between mp3 and its wav counterpart however there are many many permutations of mp3 like variable or fixed bit rate so there is no fixed kind of mp3 so I would avoid attempting to worry about how big a wav file will be once converted from mp3 ...  wav is by definition not compressed ... also there are several different flavors of wav codec as well ( integer or float for example ) ... bit depth,  sample rate and endianness are the three bedrock attributes of raw audio which is what a wav file encodes

Comment: @ScottStensland  Hmm, I understand, thanks.  So, if my backend can only handle an 8mb wav file, and I have users uploading or recording mp3s of various sizes that need to be converted, am I out of luck for trying to restrict them? Or do I just have to have very severe limitations on how big the mp3's can be?

Comment: you could limit upload mp3 size to 1mb as typically a 1:10 ratio happens which may result in wav about 10mb ...  a one channel file ( mono ) will maximize audio clip duration time available for a given file size limit whereas two channel ( stereo ) will halve the listening time

Comment: @ScottStensland it does sound like some measures like this will have to be taken.  Thank you!

Comment: @ScottStensland 1 MB!  That's not much duration at all.  Also, for a 1:10 ratio, that would have to be a very low bitrate.  Okay for voice, awful for music.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've been working on converting .mp3 files uploaded by a user into .wav format to be handled by the back-end.

Why?  This is only necessary if you're doing something with the raw PCM data.  In most cases, you can leave it as the original final that was uploaded to you.

> I've been following this example

That example is only useful if you need to convert client-side.  If converting on the server, it would be much more efficient for you to use something like FFmpeg to do the conversion for you.

> but the resultant .wav is bigger

WAV files usually store raw PCM.  This works by quantifying a pressure level thousands of times per second.  It allows for lossless editing, but isn't very efficient.  We don't "hear" pressure changes directly, we hear frequencies.  And, there are some evolutionary changes to what we hear as well.  (For example, if there are loud sounds at the same time as quiet sounds, we're not going to notice those quiet sounds.  Our brain is searching for the lion about to eat us rather than the trickling stream across the way.)

MP3 works by taking advantage of the way we hear and perceive sound to take up less space.  Processing is done in the frequency domain.  More bandwidth is spent on louder sounds than quieter sounds.  The timing of some sounds gets muddled a bit.  Rather than working on the individual sample level, short blocks of time ("frames") are processed together.  MP3 is lossy, but designed to lose the parts of sound that matter less.  In the process, it can sound close to "transparent" at like 1/7th the bandwidth of the original PCM.

Your raw PCM in your WAV file is always going to be the largest file size.  If you need to reduce size, it's not the right tool for the job.

Comment: I can tell you that the answer to your first few questions is because the back-end can only handle WAV files, and it was decided that the front end would handle the conversion.  However, your answer leads me to think I should recommend a different approach.  Thanks!

Comment: @jdmac Yeah, I'd do that conversion server-side, to reduce upload size and to maximize compatibility and consistency with what the user sends.  And if possible, always keep a copy of the original file around.  Storage is cheap, and you never know when you might want to re-convert.  (For example, you may decide in the future that you actually want those lossy copies begin with.  Or, you might need to re-extract some metadata.  Been there, done that.  :-)  Definitely keep that file around archived.)